# Encryption Test

Tags: postgresql, encryption, postgresql-11

I'm using PostgreSQL-11 and I've been given a text string to decrypt as a test.  I've got the details of how it was encrypted and its very simple.  When I try to decrypt using `select pgp_sym_decrypt(text::bytea,'the key','cipher-algo=aes256')` I get the error Wrong key or corrupt data.  I can't use the decrypt function because I get the error cipher algorithm is not available.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the format specified by PGP, then the algo used for encryption is stored in the header, and that of course will be used for decryption.  Trying to manually specify a algo to use for decryption is pointless.

Here is a working example of encryption and decryption:

```
select pgp_sym_decrypt(
    pgp_sym_encrypt('foobar','the key','cipher-algo=aes256'),
    'the key'
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer.  I need to read up on encryption again but that has worked very well and allowed me to move on.

Comment: @jjanes The example works as a single statement. But I am on postgres14 and when breaking up the encyrpt and decrypt into separate statement, I am getting Wrong Key or Corrupt Data error as the original post states. Why does it work as a single statement and not as separate statements?

Comment: @kravb Works for me as two separate statement as well, when done carefully.  I'd guess when you copy the output of one to be in the input of the other, it gets garbled, like maybe some surrounding spaces or delimiters are included, or you have quoting/escaping problems.